# How to call sub function of a different function from current function in ksh?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, function

In this is the scenario, need to call `func1` from `Main_Func`. How do I call it?

```
Main_Func() {
<code>

}
Initialize_func() {

  func1() {

  <code>

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `func1` to be defined, you will first have to have called `Initialize_func` at least once.  Then you may call `func1` as just `func1`.

Example:

```
outer1 () {
    echo 'in outer1'
    inner
}

outer2 () {
    echo 'in outer2'

    inner () {
        echo 'in inner'
    }
}

# First example explained below:
outer1

# Second example explained below:
outer2
outer1
```

Calling `outer1` without calling `outer2` in this example will not work since `inner` is not yet defined:

```
$ ksh93 script.sh
in outer1
script.sh[3]: inner: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Calling `outer2` first and then `outer1` works:

```
$ ksh93 script.sh
in outer2
in outer1
in inner
```

---

`ksh` will put your `func1` function in the same "scope" as the other functions. It's not as in C++ or other object oriented languages that `func1` somehow becomes a sub-function or method in some inner scope of `Initialize_func`.

This is regardless of whether you use the Bourne shell function syntax as above or define your functions using the `function` keyword of the Korn shell.

Comment: Note that anyway when using the Bourne function syntax (`foo() command`) as opposed to the Korn one (`function foo { ...; }`), ksh93 doesn't do any local scope at all even for variables. Still, functions defined within functions using the Korn syntax are not local to the function either.

Comment: Thanks for the Gyan ! So, even sub functions will be under same scope of enclosing function in shell scripting! --- point noted.